# How can i change ionic navbar text?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

This my code...

```
    <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
```

I dont know how can I change the header bar text.

Answer (score 0):

might be useful to you. The nav title directive replaces an ionNavBar title text with custom HTML from within an ionView template. This gives each view the ability to specify its own custom title element, such as an image or any HTML, rather than being text-only. Alternatively, text-only titles can be updated using the view-title ionView attribute.

Note that ion-nav-title must be an immediate descendant of the ion-view or ion-nav-bar element (basically don’t wrap it in another div).

Usage

```
<ion-nav-bar>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>
      <img src="logo.svg">
    </ion-nav-title>
    <ion-content>
      Some super content here!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a title of "MySideMenuTitle" — change your example as follows:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-balanced">
      <h1 class="title">MySideMenuTitle</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        ...
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

For a regular Ionic view, changing the nav title is easier:

```
<ion-view view-title="MyTitle">
  <ion-content>
    ...
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```